# Sending from server-side to client-side multiple PartialViews asynchronously with an undefined delay

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been lurking for about a hour trying to find a solution or a pattern to do it (title reference)..
Let me give you an example for what I mean:

```
Client-to-Server: Hey, I want information about "ww2" //using jquery's ajax .post() method
Server-to-Client: Ok, got your request, prepare to receive data asynchronously.
Server-to-Client: "World War II happen in 1939 to 1945"
//after couple of seconds
Server-to-Client: "The Alliance won the war."
//some more delay
Server-to-Client: "bla bla bla"
Server-to-Client: "thats it, im done for now".
```

now obviously the client will display the data as soon as it is received using jquery.
My main question is, how can I possible invoke a `HttpPOST` on an `Action` on the server and return many `PartialView`s asynchronously?

If there is any other way/idea with a sample, it will be well appreciated.

Comment: You are writing it as if every person that has touched a computer must know any kind of library in javascript..
I'll check it out, any more suggestions?

Comment: http://signalr.net/  Not offhand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SignalR is one option

but if you wanna do yourself instead of inherit your controllers class from `Controller`, inherit it from `AsyncController`. 
Controllers that inherit from `AsyncController` can process asynchronous requests, and they can still service synchronous action methods.

```
public class HomeController : AsyncController 
     {
         public void ExtensiveTaskActionAsync() 
         {
             AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
             Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoExtensiveTask());
         }

         private void DoExtensiveTask()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // some task that could be extensive
            AsyncManager.Parameters["message"] = "hello world";
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        }


        public ActionResult ExtensiveTaskActionCompleted(string message) 
        {
            //task complete so, return the result
            return View();
        }
    }
```